# How to get resolved object in the child component from the ui-router state?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Here is my code:

```
export function resolveUser(userService: UserService) {
  return userService.get();
}
 let homeState = {
  parent: 'app',
  name: 'home',
  url: '/home'
  component: HomeComponent,
  resolve: [
    { token: 'currentUser', deps: [UserService], resolveFn: resolveUser },
  ]
};

@Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   template: '<app-menu></app-menu>'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    @Input('currentUser') user: User; //user exists
}

@Component({
   selector: 'app-menu',
   template: '<div>{{user.name}}</div>'
})
export class MenuComponent {
    @Input('currentUser') user: User; //user undefined
}
```

currentUser field in the HomeComponent is defined, but in the MenuComponent is not defined, although MenuComponent is a child of HomeComponent. 
How cat I get currentUser in the MenuComponent?